# How to parse a WordPress CSV export using Python

Tags: python, wordpress, csv, plone, transmogrifier

I need to import content from WordPress into Plone, a Python-based CMS, and I have a dump of the posts table as a huge CSV vanilla file using ";" as a delimiter.

The problem is the standard CSV reader from the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is not smart enough to parse the HTML content inside a row (the `post_content` field).

For instance, when the parser encounters something like `<p>&nbsp;</p>` it interprets the semicolon as a field delimiter and I end up with more items than fields and with fields with wrong content.

Is there any other option to solve this kind of issues? Processing the row with a regex seems pretty scary to me.

Comment: Hum. Would it be okay if you first converted all the HTML &nbsp; into spaces and then tried csv.reader?

Comment: can you add a sample of your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some additional research, I discovered the `excel-tab` dialect by reading the text of the [PEP 0305](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0305/) (which proposed the addition of the cvs module to Python); this is mentioned in the module documentation, but I haven't noticed at first.

I then re-exported the posts using a tab as a delimiter (`\t`).

[image]

I made a test reading a batch of 1,000 rows and found no errors at all.

Comment: I would have thought that exporting with:  `fields enclosed by "` would have solved the issue you mentioned, whatever delimiter you were using

Comment: In my last test, we should not mark "Remove CRLF characters within fields" to make transmogrify.wordpress detect paragraphs

Answer (score 1):

The CSV module provides the [`escapechar`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.escapechar) format parameter, which allows you to escape the delimiter (which you have set to semicolon).  If you can provide `escapechar='\\'` in the call to `csv.reader()`, you could then replace the character `\` in your CSV file with `\\`, and replace `&nbsp;` with `&nbsp\;` (using a text editor's find/replace option).

Answer (score 1):

Another option, for smaller sites, could be using [pywordpress](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywordpress), a pythonic interface to WordPress XML-RPC API.